# Function and strings, checking if input strings match

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, char

I want to create a function called `LetterDifference(char *wordA, char *wordB)`

I want the function to scan through both words and return 1 if there is a ONE letter difference between the words. For example if

`wordA = cool` and

`wordB = tool`

Note: `WordA` and `WordB` are always the same length

I want the function to return 1

This is what I have attempted, my code wont compile, I think that there is an error with my understanding. Could anyone help me out?

```
int LetterDifference(char *wordA, char *wordB)
{
    int i;
    int count = strlen(word1);
    while (i < strlen(wordA)) {
        if (wordA[i] == wordB[i]) {
            count = count - 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to return something in the case of count != 1.

Comment: "*my code wont compile*" and the compiler gives you which reasons?

Comment: "my code wont compile." Did you try reading and interpreting the error?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Could you please explain?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual errors you get. Copy-paste them (as text) in full and complete. And please take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use the command line options `-Wall -Wextra` for your compiler and look at the output. Do what the compiler tells you to do.

Comment: Usually, when a compiler fails to compile a program, it tells you why it failed :-)

Comment: You should initialize your variable `i`

Comment: Putting aside that `word1` is undefined, the code accesses `wordB` out of bound if it is shorter then `wordA`.

Comment: Despite the fact, that `word1` does not exist, you don't ensure, that `wordA` and `wordB` do have the same length, which leads to an out-of-bounds access (undefined behavoir). Also `i` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

the logic is pretty simple behind this @new coder.

I would like to point out a few errors first which need to rectified.

1. The control goes out of bounds in case `wordA` and `wordB` are of unequal lengths. You need to make sure that both words are of equal length before proceeding any futher.
2. `word1`, whose length you have used to initialize the `count` variable to, is a variable which doesn't exist. It should instead be `wordA`.
3. There is no return value for cases where `count`, turns out to be NOT 1.

**The solution:**

You just need to loop from 0 till length of any one string. Check corresponding elements/characters from both strings at each index, for each unequal character, increment the `count`er variable. If the `count`er is finally equal to `1`. it means there is a one-letter difference.

I have posted the code below. It also makes sure the user only enters strings of equal length. Hope it helps.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int LetterDifference(char[] , char[] );

int main() {
  int l1, l2, flag = 0, res;
  char a[10], b[10];
  while(flag==0) {
    printf("\nEnter 2 words each of the same length:");
    printf("\nenter the 1st word: ");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("\nenter the 2nd word: ");
    scanf("%s",&b);
    l1 = strlen(a);
    l2 = strlen(b);
    if(l1==l2) {
      flag = 1;
    }
    else {
      printf("\nlengths of the words are unequal...enter again!!!");
      flag = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("\n%s\n%s",a,b);
  res = LetterDifference(a, b);
  if(res==1) {
    printf("\nThere is a 1-letter difference.");
  }
  else {
    printf("\nNO one letter difference.");
  }
  return 0;
}

int LetterDifference(char wordA[], char wordB[])
{
    int i, count = 0;
    int j,c[strlen(wordA)];
    //use the following for loop if you are looking to match corresponding characters from each word
    //for(i = 0; i < strlen(wordA); i++) {
    //  if(wordA[i]!=wordB[i]) {
    //    count++;
    //  }
    //}
    //use the following for loop if you are looking to match any characters from word regardless of the order in which they appear
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(wordA); i++) {
      c[i]=0;
      for(j = 0; j < strlen(wordB); j++) {
        if(wordA[i]==wordB[j]) {
          c[i]++;
        }
      }
      if(c[i]==0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
*CASE 1: Considering the word order*

> Enter 2 words each of the same length:
>
> enter the 1st word:  abcd
>
> enter the 2nd word:  abcz
>
> abcd
>
> abcz
>
> There is a 1-letter difference.

another input

> Enter 2 words each of the same length:
>
> enter the 1st word:  qqqq
>
> enter the 2nd word:  q
>
> lengths of the words are unequal...enter again!!!
>
> Enter 2 words each of the same length:
>
> Enter 2 words each of the same length:
>
> enter the 1st word:  qqqq
>
> enter the 2nd word:  aaaa
>
> qqqq
>
> aaaa
>
> NO one letter difference.

*CASE 2: regardless of character order*

> Enter 2 words each of the same length:
>
> enter the 1st word:  qwewew
>
> enter the 2nd word:  ewwewf
>
> qwewew
>
> ewwewf
>
> There is a 1-letter difference.

Comment: What if words are suppose like `abcdef` and `abdefg` clearly there is only one letter difference.

Comment: You'e got a point @kiranBiradar, I agree. But I'm not sure if OP is exactly looking for differences in any part of the word regardless of letter-order. As per the sample output given by the OP, I have checked only corresponding elements.

Comment: Okay. Please mention the same as part of answer as side note I will upvote.

Comment: Sure bro, will do. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>
    int LetterDifference(char *wordA, char *wordB)
    {
        int count = 0 , i;
       for(i = 0 ;wordA[i] ; i++ )
       if(wordA[i]!=wordB[i])
           count++;
     return count;
  }
  int main()
  {
          char res = 0 ,word1[10],word2[10];
          printf("Enter the first word : ");scanf("%s",word1);
          printf("Enter the second word : ");scanf("%s",word2);

          res = LetterDifference( word1 , word2);
          if(res == 1)
          printf("Yes\n");
          else
          printf("No\n");
 }
```

Comment: check this code , it will work

Comment: What if `wordB` is smaller than `wordA` ? You will access out of bound for `wordB`.

Comment: Inside the for loop why did you go 
;WordA[i]? Why not strlen(wordA[i]) because we want to loop through a given range?

Comment: @new coder : string has its terminating character '\0' thats why it is not necessory to use strlen.

Comment: @kiran Biradar : I am agreed with you as new-learner explained problem in that way only I consider the scenerio . Solution : add the if( strlen(wordA) != strlen(wordB)){ return (any value greater than 1)}